# How to make the defined `\oline` adjust with texts?

Tags: math-mode, accents

First a MWE is as follows：

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\newcommand*\oline[1]{%
\kern.2em%add the left space
\vbox{%
\hrule height 0.3pt%  % Line above with certain width
\kern0.3ex% % Distance between line and content
\hbox{%
\kern -0.1em%  % Distance between content and left side of box, negative values for lines shorter than content
\ifmmode#1\else\ensuremath{#1}\fi%  % The content, typeset in dependence of mode
\kern -0.1em% % Distance between content and left side of box, negative values for lines shorter than content
}% end of hbox
}% end of vbox
\kern.2em} %add the right spacce

\begin{document}
\[2^{\oline{S}abc}=\oline{S}0.\]

\end{document}
```

In the example, I define a command `\oline` to produce the above line as my desired. But it can't adjust with the texts as you see in the following figure: `\oline{S}` is bigger than `abc` while in fact it should be the same size as `abc`.

[image]

**Question:** ***who can help me improve it to make it adjust with the texts?***

Comment: What's wrong in `\overline{S}`?

Comment: @egreg the line produced by `\overline` is too long and too thick, and also when to use `\overline` iterably, for example `\overline{\overline{A}}`, the space between produced lines is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few improvements to apply.

1. When you open an `\hbox`, TeX is not in math mode any longer, so `\ifmmode` will always return false.
2. You need to take into account the current math style, which is done with `\mathpalette`.
3. The hardwired `0.3ex` will yield too big a spacing in superscripts.

Here's a proposal, with a comparison with the standard `\bar` command.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\oline[1]{{\mspace{2mu}\mathpalette\o@line{#1}\mspace{2mu}}}
\newcommand*\o@line[2]{%
  \vbox{
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mspace{2mu}$}
    \hrule height 0.3pt
    \kern\wd\z@
    \hbox{$\m@th\mspace{-2mu}#1#2\mspace{-2mu}$}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
2^{\oline{S}abc}=\oline{S}0 \\
2^{\bar{S}abc}=\bar{S}0
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]